# Early-morning food at Népliget bus station in Budapest?

Tags: food-and-drink, buses, shopping, budapest

I have to catch an early-morning bus out of Budapest on a weekday. Can I buy food (a pastry, or even just a candy bar) sometime around 06:00 at Népliget bus station in Budapest? How about coffee?

Comment: It has been many years since I was in that situation, but, yes, I could. As a general rule of thumb, if there's a bus departing, there's someone selling something to eat and drink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BKK has a handy list about [points of sale](http://www.bkk.hu/vasarlasi-lehetosegek/viii-xi-kerulet/) in Hungarian but if you know the word "Közért" means "Grocery store" (roughly) then you can see one open 5am-10pm at the Népliget metró (underground) station. Also, it says the Relay store under ground is open from 4:30am (the one in the bus station above ground opens at 5:30am) and while their primary focus is newspapers, magazines and such they also sell candy bars and similar as you can see on this http://www.lapker.hu/index.php?mid=38 picture on the official Relay store page. I can't remember for sure but they might even have sandwiches.

The Lipóti Pékség (= Lipóti Bakery, VERY YUMMY! not only their pastries but they partner with Cserpes diaries and they have some seriously tasty stuff) http://lipotipekseg.hu/uzletek/ says it's also open from 5am. Similarly, they might have sandwiches but I am not sure either as I haven't been at this location.

Comment: Yep, Lipóti Pékség was one of the open bakeries. I got a pastry from there; it was good, but one from a nondescript stall at platform level was even better--and cheaper!

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't moved 9000 km away to ever again eat at a nondescript stall in Hungary when visiting. Perhaps you shouldn't either.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can buy food and coffee early in the morning at the Népliget bus station in Budapest.

This morning, when I was there at around 6:00, roughly half of the numerous bakeries and convenience stores in the bus station and adjoining subway station were open.